# why this code work on local host and not work on hosting

Tags: php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ar" lang="ar">
    <head>
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset= utf-8" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <title>ahmed fakhr el din</title>
    </head>


    <body>

<div id="regform">
<h2> Ù†Ù…ÙˆØ°Ø¬ ØªØ³Ø¬ÙŠÙ„</h2>
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){// Click on complete button

        $error=array();
        if(empty($_POST['uname']) || trim($_POST['uname'])=="")
            $error[]="Ø®Ø·Ø£ : Ø®Ø§Ù†Ø© Ø§Ø³Ù… Ø§Ù„Ù…Ø³ØªØ®Ø¯Ù… ÙØ§Ø±ØºØ©";
        if(empty($_POST['fname']) || trim($_POST['fname'])=="")
            $error[]="Ø®Ø·Ø£:Ø®Ø§Ù†Ø© Ø§Ù„Ø§Ø³Ù… Ø§Ù„Ø§ÙˆÙ„ ÙØ§Ø±ØºØ©";
        if(empty($_POST['password']) || trim($_POST['password'])=="")
            $error[]="Ø®Ø·Ø£ : Ø®Ø§Ù†Ø© Ø§Ù„ÙƒÙ„Ù…Ø© Ø§Ù„Ø³Ø±ÙŠØ© ÙØ§Ø±ØºØ©";
        if(empty($_POST['password2']) || trim($_POST['password2'])=="")
            $error[]="Ø®Ø·Ø£ Ø®Ø§Ù†Ø©  ØªØ£ÙƒÙŠØ¯ Ø§Ù„ÙƒÙ„Ù…Ø© Ø§Ù„Ø³Ø±ÙŠØ© ÙØ§Ø±ØºØ©";
        if(empty($_POST['email'])|| trim($_POST['email'])=="")
            $error[]="Ø®Ø·Ø£ : Ø®Ø§Ù†Ø© Ø§Ù„Ø¨Ø±ÙŠØ¯ Ø§Ù„Ø§Ù„ÙƒØªØ±ÙˆÙ†ÙŠ ÙØ§Ø±ØºØ©";
        if(empty($_POST['email2'])|| trim($_POST['email2'])=="")
            $error[]="Ø®Ø·Ø£ : Ø®Ø§Ù†Ø© ØªØ£ÙƒÙŠØ¯ Ø§Ù„Ø¨Ø±ÙŠØ¯ Ø§Ù„Ø§Ù„ÙƒØªØ±ÙˆÙ†ÙŠ ÙØ§Ø±ØºØ©";
        if(empty($_POST['age'])|| trim($_POST['age'])=="")
            $error[]="Ø®Ø·Ø£ :Ø®Ø§Ù†Ø© Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ù…Ø± ÙØ§Ø±ØºØ©";

        if(strlen($_POST['uname'])<4)
            $error[]="Ø­Ø·Ø£ :  ÙŠØ¬Ø¨ Ø§Ù† ÙŠØªÙƒÙˆÙ† Ø§Ø³Ù… Ø§Ù„Ù…Ø³ØªØ®Ø¯Ù…Ù† Ø§ÙƒØ«Ø± 4 Ø­Ø±ÙˆÙ";

        if(strlen($_POST['password'])<4 || strlen($_POST['password2'])<4)
            $error[]="Ø®Ø·Ø£ Ø§Ù„ÙƒÙ„Ù…Ø© Ø§Ù„Ø³Ø±ÙŠØ© ÙŠØ¬Ø¨ Ø§Ù† ØªØªÙƒÙˆÙ† Ù…Ù† Ø§ÙƒØ«Ø± Ù…Ù† 6 Ø­Ø±ÙˆÙ";

        if($_POST['password']!=$_POST['password2'])
            $error[]="Ø®Ø·Ø£ : Ø§Ù„ÙƒÙ„Ù…Ø§Øª Ø§Ù„Ø³Ø±ÙŠØ© ØºÙŠØ± Ù…ØªØ·Ø§Ø¨Ù‚Ø©";
            //Validating Emails 

            if(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9](.[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])+$/",$_POST['email'])
                ||
                !preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9](.[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])+$/",$_POST['email2']))
        $error[]="Ø®Ø·Ø£: Ø§Ù„Ø¨Ø±ÙŠØ¯ Ø§Ù„Ø§Ù„ÙƒØªØ±ÙˆÙ†ÙŠ ØºÙŠØ± ØµØ§Ù„Ø­";



        if($_POST['email']!=$_POST['email2'])
            $error[]="Ø®Ø·Ø£ : Ø§Ù„Ø¨Ø±ÙŠØ¯ Ø§Ù„Ø§Ù„ÙƒØªØ±ÙˆÙ†ÙŠ ØºÙŠØ± Ù…ØªØ·Ø§Ø¨Ù‚";

        if(!is_numeric($_POST['age']))
            $error[]="Ø®Ø·Ø£ : Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ù…Ø± Ø§Ù„Ù…Ø¯Ø®Ù„ Ù„ÙŠØ³ Ù‚ÙŠÙ…Ø© Ø±Ù‚Ù…ÙŠØ©";


if(sizeof($error)>0){
            echo "<div id=\"error\">";
            echo "<ul>";                
    foreach($error as $k=>$v){
            echo "<li> ";
            echo $v;
            echo "</li>";           
        }
            echo "</ul>";
            echo "</div>";

        }


            else{
        include "conf.php";
                // Random confirmation code
                $confirm_code=uniqid(rand());
                $username=$_POST['uname'];
                $fname=$_POST['fname'];
                $password=$_POST['password'];
                $email=$_POST['email'];
                $age=$_POST['age'];
                $gender=$_POST['gender'];
                $adduser= mysql_query("INSERT INTO USERS VALUES('$confirm_code','$username','$fname','$password','$email','$age','$gender')");
                 // send e-mail to ...
                  $to=$email;

                 // Your subject
              $subject="Your confirmation link here";

                   // From
              $header="from: your name <your email>";

                   // Your message
              $message="Your Comfirmation link \r\n";
              $message.="Click on this link to activate your account \r\n";
              $message.="http://www.sufiacademy.net/confirmation.php?passkey=$confirm_code";
                        // send email
              $sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
                if($adduser and $sentmail){

                    echo "<div id=\"succes\">";
                    echo "  register succesfully";
                    echo "</div>";

                }

            }

        }



?>
    <ul>
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
        <li><label>Ø§Ø³Ù… Ø§Ù„Ù…Ø³ØªØ®Ø¯Ù… :</label> <span><input type="text" name="uname" /></span> </li>
        <li><label> Ø§Ù„Ø§Ø³Ù… Ø§Ù„Ø§ÙˆÙ„: </label> <span><input type="text" name="fname" /></span></li>
        <li><label> Ø§Ù„ÙƒÙ„Ù…Ø© Ø§Ù„Ø³Ø±ÙŠØ©: </label> <span><input type="password" name="password" /></span> </li>
        <li><label> ØªØ£ÙƒÙŠØ¯ Ø§Ù„ÙƒÙ„Ù…Ø© Ø§Ù„Ø³Ø±ÙŠØ©: </label>  <span><input type="password" name="password2" /></span></li>
        <li><label> Ø§Ù„Ø¨Ø±ÙŠØ¯ Ø§Ù„Ø§Ù„ÙƒØªØ±ÙˆÙ†ÙŠ: </label>  <span><input type="text" name="email" /></span></li>
        <li><label> ØªØ£ÙƒÙŠØ¯ Ø§Ù„Ø¨Ø±ÙŠØ¯ Ø§Ù„Ø§Ù„ÙƒØªØ±ÙˆÙ†ÙŠ: </label>  <span><input type="text" name="email2" /></span> </li>
        <li><label> Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ù…Ø±: </label>  <span><input type="text" name="age" /></span></li>
        <li><label> Ø§Ù„Ø¬Ù†Ø³: </label><span><select name="gender"><option>Ø°ÙƒØ±</option> <option>Ø§Ù†Ø«Ù‰</option> </select> </span> </li>
        <li> <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Ø§ÙƒÙ…Ø§Ù„" name="submit"/> </li>
        </form>
    </ul>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: WTF, would you format this a bit please?

Comment: What, specifically, isn't working? What do you expect to see? What are you seeing instead?

Comment: include path not set correctly? mysql not available? mail server not configured? Without knowing what doesn't work, it's anybody's guess

Comment: There's certainly some nasty SQL injection security fail in there...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a problem with the server's character set? Without more spezifications about the problem, I can'g make a better guess...

EDIT:

Also if you are not going to fill every column in the table or not inserting the values in the right order, you need to specify the columns you are going to insert to, like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (col1,col2) VALUES( "val1" ,"val2");
```

(See [MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/insert.html))

It's also not a good idea, to write the users input in the table as he made it, use

```
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[...]);
```

at least to avert SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Does the server have a valid mail configuration? Verify, that the mail() function works and can send emails!

You should also check that the database is created using UTF-8 encoding. Check it's charset.

Maybe you should also check if the table is called USERS or users. MySQL is case-sensitive.

Comment: the server send email but not insert in database

Comment: You clearly didn't pay any attention to the comments made about your code when you asked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768062/problem-with-insert-in-database-code .... trap the response from mysql_query to see if it's an error, and get the error message)

Comment: the code work good and insert in database in localhost but not in hosting

Comment: @magy - please, please, please... put a test in your code after the database connect/select (in conf.php) and the mysql query to test for errors and display or log any error message

Comment: this is my config.php code  
<?php

$host='localhost';
$db_name = 'first';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';

$con = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die ("Not Connected");
$x = mysql_select_db($db_name, $con) or die ("MySQL error");

?>

Comment: Sebastian Hoitz you are goooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooood maan

Comment: it is work now and the problem is USERS not correct the correct is users , when i replace name database insert loooooool